# $InputFileName backwards compatibility

Tags: packages, version-7, version-6

What would be a good replacement for `$InputFileName` (which has been added recently to Mathematica 8) to achieve backwards compatibility with let's say M6 and M7?

I am using it for loading auxiliary data from a package file and found that it is a convenient way to use relative paths for this purpose. However, I am not sure how to achieve this in M6 and M7.

For example,

```
$PackageDir=DirectoryName[$InputFileName];
svgParser=XML`Parser`InitializeXMLParser["svg",
     FileNameJoin[{$PackageDir,"Cache/svg10.dtd"}]]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try

```
System`Private`$InputFileName
```

Seems to work on M7, not sure about M6.

Comment: it also seems to work with version 6...

Comment: @AlbertRetey So more the better! Thanks for checking, I don't currently have V6 installed.