# Using NotebookDirectory in batch-mode

Tags: front-end, kernel, files-and-directories, linux, windows

I am running *Mathematica* via the terminal (Linux) and my `.m`-script contains the command:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
```

such that the directory is set to that of the notebook. When I run this with `math -noprompt -script test.m` I get two errors:

> `FrontEndObject::notavail A front end is not available; certain operations require a front end`

and

> `SetDirectory:fstr: File specification NotebookDirectory[$Failed] is not a string of one or more characters`

In Windows this works perfectly. Does this mean that setting the notebook directory is not supported in the Linux terminal as it is in Windows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is AFAIK not dependent on the OS but how you run *Mathematica*. If you only run the Kernel in batch mode, it is `$Input` which you can ask to get a file path of the script just running. It sometimes needs some extra care as it will not always hold the full file name if I remember correctly. I'd start to just print its content in your script and then add/change what's necessary.

As rm-rf has noted there is now (introduced in version 8) `$InputFileName` which seems to not be affected by the potential problems I mentioned.

In case that anyone needs this for versions before 8, here is a rough sketch of what should work there:

```
 StringReplace[First[FileNames[$Input, $Path]], 
    "." ~~ "/" | $PathnameSeparator ~~ rest__ :> 
    ToFileName[{Directory[]}, rest]]
```

to make it reliable you would of course need to check whether `$Input` is defined at all and whether `FindFiles` did find the input file at all. This of course assumes that `$Path` and `Directory[]` are still the same as when the input file was loaded. There could be additional problems which I now don't remember anymore.

Since version 6 there is also an undocumented `` System`Private`$InputFileName `` as Leonid has mentioned but with it you also might not always get a full file path, but could only get a relative path. So my technique to add that if necessary might be useful even with newer versions.

For a script file it is not `$Path` but rather something like `GetEnvironment["PATH"]` which will contain the information about what's to be added to relative pathes, but the details then will become slightly os dependent. But I think that for all versions that support the script environments `$InputFileName` does reliably contain the full path, and that probably is not completely by accident...

Comment: Don't you mean `$InputFileName`?

Comment: @rm-rf: not really, but I better should have meant that :-). It most probably will not have the problems that I can vaguely remember...

Comment: Yeah, I think it is better. `$Input` will only give "file" when you do `<<file`, whereas `$InputFileName` will give the full path, which makes it easy to set the directory using `ParentDirectory` (at least, that's how I remember the difference between the two). It was introduced in v8

Comment: @rm-rf: that explains why I didn't know it: the last time I had use for that was before v8 came out. Actually I remembered $Input because it was a real pain in the a.. to work with it for the mentioned reasons, I think I ended up searching what `$Input` gave me in `$Path`...

Comment: +1. @rm-rf, Albert: In fact,`$InputFileName` was there since at least V7, but it was hidden, as I described [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2842/inputfilename-backwards-compatibility/2843#2843).

Comment: @Leonid: ``System`Private`$InputFileName`` was already available in version 6. I just realized that even in version 9 `$InputFileName` will sometimes only return relative file pathes, so some additional efforts as I described might be necessary to get a full path even then...

Comment: @AlbertRetey Interesting, I was not aware of this. I wonder what are the conditions for `$InputFileName` to return relative paths.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin: I must correct myself, it's just ``System`Private`$InputFileName`` which sometimes returns relative pathes, the new "official" ``System`$InputFileName`` seems to always return full pathes...

Comment: @AlbertRetey Oh, ok. This is a good news, and also interesting. I thought that these two were identical, and the public one being just an alias for the private one. Apparently they are different.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same problem as by BillyJean under Windows 7, while running a script from the command line using M9. Seems only this solution works and other solutions do not work:

```
dir = DirectoryName[$InputFileName];
filename = FileNameJoin[{dir, "nw.txt"}];
val = ToLowerCase[Import[filename]];
```

I could not test in previous versions of M. Perhaps a change.